# Initializing Django model field with the model field from the same Model temporarily

Tags: python, django

I am building a trip reservation app in Django 2.1 and have some problem with updating available seats in the car for the trip. Your help would be greatly appreciated)

Here below, I have my first model, I am trying to initialize `available_seats` with `seats` just for the first time when the model will be created. First, I tried below method

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=120) 
    time_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    arrival_time = models.DateTimeField()
    trip_cost = models.IntegerField()
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seats = models.IntegerField()
    available_seats = models.IntegerField(default=seats)
```

yes, this method doesn't work because it is not possible to assign a variable to the one which is not defined yet. Thus, I come with solutions that I need to rewrite the `save()` method of the model or use signals to accomplish what i want. So, I did:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=120) 
    time_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    arrival_time = models.DateTimeField()
    trip_cost = models.IntegerField()
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seats = models.IntegerField()
    available_seats = models.IntegerField()



    #rewriting save() method
    # def save(self, created=False, *args, **kwargs):
    #     if created:
    #         self.available_seats = self.seats
    #         super().save(*args, **kwargs)


#using signals
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Trip)
def default_available_seats(sender, instance=Trip, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
    instance.available_seats = instance.seats
```

These two ways will set my `Trip.available_seats = seats`, but the thing is that now my `available_seats` is always related and depend on my `seats`. I cannot update the value `available_seats` separately, whenever I update `seats` available seats will change automatically, but I don't want it. I want `available_seats` have the `seats` value just for the beginning when the Trip Model was created. Because available_seats will be changes once someone will reserve a seat.

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?
Looking for your operative help)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need to add a kwarg of your own to the save method. You can simply find out if the object is being created by checking the pk: if `if self.pk` evaluates to `True` then this object is being updated if `False` then it is being created. Also the pre save signal does not have the `created` argument that is present with the post save signal because the database does not know if the entry exists before actually trying to save.

Comment: Create a "SeatReservation" model with a foreign key to the `Trip` model and change `available_seats` to be a calculated property instead of a field, it can be calculated by subtracting the number of related "SeatReservation"s from the number of seats